# What to consider when getting started with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've got experience with MySQL, DB2, and Oracle, but aside from writing a few queries, I've never used SQL Server.

My question is a three parter:

1) For a developer, what are some good "free" client tools to look at, and why (by "free" I mean open source, freeware, or the tools that come with SQL Server itself)?

2) I plan to run Developer or Express Edition on my workstation for development, and either Standard or Enterprise Edition in the testing and production environments.  What methods exist if any for transferring data between different servers and the different editions?

3) Are there any common pitfalls that someone like me (who is used to the other database systems that I mentioned) might encountered during development?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SQL Server Management Studio which comes with SQL Server (any editions), or you can download it separately. SQL Server Profiler which doesn't come with Express.
2. Management studio has tools for backup/restore database. You can also consider detach/attach method to synchronize db .
3. It's hard to say. But if you had Mysql experience you will be pleasantly surprised by SQL Server.
   **UPDATE**

   1. There are so many things that each DB vendor implements differently that it's really hard to focus on some of them. One thing I was not used before is that SQL Server doesn't let unique columns to have more than 1 NULL value(there is a workaround though)

Comment: I like gbn's answer too, but this one has some more detail so it wins out.

Answer (score 2):

1. SQL Server Express with tools.
2. All editions have the same SQL language features and code is 100% portable between them. There are 3rd party tools to synch changes, but moving entire DBs is easy using inbuilt tools.
3. Nah. The problem with databases is SQL and set theory, not the choice of RDBMS. If you understand databases/SQL you'll be OK.

Comment: Issue with 3 is that most people never grab SQL properly. Even most developers using databases just "cook boiled eggs every day" so to say, and are lost on anything more comples than a seriously simple insert / select etc.

Comment: @TomTom:  True enough... I have pretty good skills when it comes to writing efficient queries which I am sure are transferrable to SQL server, but I was really hoping to identify any known issues to take into account with SQL server.